# Electric field of a hemisphere

Tags: electrical-engineering

My question is to calculate the electric field of a point in the Z axis of a empty hemisphere with a superficial density $\sigma$, but I have to do it from the formula of the electric field of a ring: $\vec{E}= \frac{\rho_l z a}{2 \epsilon_0 (z^2+a^2)} \hat{k}$, where $\rho_l$ is the lineal density, $z$ the z coordinate, $a$ the radius of the ring and $\epsilon_0$ is the electric constant. I have tried to express $\rho_l=\frac{dq}{dl}=\frac{\sigma dA}{dl}=\sigma dz'$ but if I change $a$ with $z'$ (because the radium of each ring changes) and I do the integral, I don't get the right answer. I know that I'm doing something wrong, and I'd appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework problem and because it belongs on physics.SE .

Comment: I have asked the same in physics and they have voted this question as an off-topic question. I'm studying telecomunications engineering and I don't even have to know this, it is for curiosity. I thought that the objective of comunities was to learn and help other people, but they only want serious and difficult question. However, you can't be an engineer from the void.

Comment: Curiosity or homework: I would also vote totally off topic for the following reasons. First: for Electric fields we note $\vec{E}$ and not $\vec{B}$. Second you are here working with non Gaussian surfaces. So in any case you should at least explain the motivation for such a question: how did you came to ask yourself this question? Only then we may be able to help.

Comment: Ok,thanks for listening to me. I'm sorry about the denotation of the electric field, I'm also working with magnetic field and I made a mistake. Then, I came up with the idea of this surface because I did the electric field of a circular surface from the field of a ring, and then, I thought to use the same idea and process to do the field of a 3D surface. I think it's interesting for me to answer this question because if I had a good command in using superposition to calculate electric fields, I'd be able to calculate the field of any distribution easier and faster than if I integrate directly.

Comment: ok, if you want to extend your code to 3D surfaces, I can suggest you to extend it for Gaussians surfaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_surface. Next time directly ask an honest question: I made a code to measure electric fields of a wire, I would like to extend to 3D surfaces... I tried on a half sphere and it does not seems to work...

Comment: Thank you, I'm new in the comunity but I will ask better next time.